# Android 3rd party Libraries: Where to find Comprehensive list?

Tags: android, jar

Where can I find a comprehensive list of 3rd party libraries for Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My most favorite is DevAppsDirect.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect

All of the examples showcased are open source and available on github

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good **library collection**:

[**Android-Arsenal.com**](https://android-arsenal.com/)

On this site you can find a huge collection of various android libraries in different categories, including links to GitHub.